# PWM with IN-12 nixie tubes

Tags: pwm, vacuum-tube, dimming, nixie

I have some IN-12 nixie tubes and I can drive them using TPIC6B595N chip which has 50V clamping. And this chip has G pin which it is possible to use global dimming. What I questioned is which PWM frequency level should I use to maximize  life of nixie tubes and make it work. Reason why I want to dim nixie flament is to have a better looking while hours or minutes passes by. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590082/choosing-pwm-frequency-for-dimming-nixie-tubes

Comment: I didn't see a decent datasheet for the IN-12 but this[5750](https://www.hamanuals.com/S1/Common/Datashts/B-5750.pdf) datasheet has enough information to be a guide for that tube. The 5750 is tested for and evaluated for certain PWM operation. It also includes discussion about lifetime and what to do to stay on the right path there. I'd recommend looking carefully for a good datasheet on the IN-12 (sorry I didn't find one that I considered good enough) and read it carefully. The physics involved is non-trivial.